# data missing in sql database on entering through web form

Tags: asp.net

I am having a form builder that that is used to fill up the forms by users.This form is of almost 30 pages also including some mandatory field pages.My problem is that the data which is being shown in database shows no value for some pages of forms which are of mandatory fields and user cant skip them.
There are two possible cases:-
1)User has skipped these pages(having mandatory fields) through URL tampering or maybe some other way.
2)The data entered by user might be lost and not entered in database.
But i have checked error logs which show no evidence of any error or exception.
Please suggest me your solutions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tricky to answer without any code. Set a Session counter that counts as you go from page to page and if the user somehow manages to miss a page, take them back to the right page. Save the data on every page.

Comment: On each page the data is saved.Control does not go to next page unless the data is saved.